# How to Download big zip files (100- 200 MB) in iOS with Resume and Pause.

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6.1

Hi I want to download big zip Files ranging from 100-200 MB in my iOS application.

I want to resume and pause (by user) downloads and show progress of download.

and pause download when application enters background on HOME button press.

resume download when application again enters foreground.

I found different ways of downloading big files but not of

"resuming download When app enters background and resuming after app enters background"

Can anyone tell me what is the good approach of achieving this functionality in iOS (7 and 6.1) .

Any tutorial  ,link , sample code , anything which can help ....

Comment: AFNetworking -> done!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a PHP script that you pass the current byte offset where the download should start. And then, when you receive the data, you can append it to the data you already downloaded.

I'm sure this is not a perfect solution. But when you implement some checks and pass informations about the offset from the server to the client, it should be achievable.